# Not sure about the type of SQL Server lock to use for synchronization

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, synchronization

I have an ASP.NET web application that populates the SQL Server 2008 database table like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblName1 (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES(1, 2, 3)
```

I also have a separate service application that processes the contents of that table (on the background) by first renaming that table, and then by creating an empty table as such:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION

--Rename table
EXEC sp_rename 'tblName1', 'temp_tblName1'

--Create new table
CREATE TABLE tblName1(
id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
col1 INT,
col2 INT,
col3 INT
)
COMMIT

SET XACT_ABORT OFF
--Begin working with the 'temp_tblName1' table
```

What I am not sure is which SQL lock do I need to use in this situation on the `tblName1` table?

PS. To give you a frequency with which these two code samples run: first may run several times a second (although most times, less frequently), and the second one -- twice a day.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "lock", but this sounds like [Transact-SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transact-SQL).

Comment: Yes, it is t-SQL. I updated the tags. By "lock" I mean synchronization lock for the simultaneous access to the `tblName1` table.

Comment: The number of times that an `INSERT` arrives at just the right time to hit the server *between* the rename and the `CREATE` is probably miniscule - to the extent that other errors (e.g. network connection lost between machines) are more likely - so just write some robust error handling and ignore this particular situation (Or, if you're building the next world dominating web site, use Enterprise edition and partitioned tables, and never do the rename/create at all)

Comment: I would probably find a method to do this which doesn't require explicit locking (such as keeping the data in a single table with a status column, and allowing SQL Server to place its own row/table locks), but if you must lock explicitly `sp_getapplock` would probably do what you want.

Comment: if I were you, I will not rename the table. 1) keep inserting to the table in the 1st processing; 2) when doing the 2nd process, which is about twice a day, 'remember' the data you should use (i.e. use id). after processing, purge the data. this way, you do not need to worry about lock.

Comment: I personal use `Mutex` on my programs for action like that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Nice ideas. Still, if I want to go with a lock. @TimMedora: I'm not sure how I'd use `sp_getapplock` lock. Can you show with the code?

Comment: I am not sure I follow your question. Are you talking about locks in SQL Server or Locks in asp.net code? When you try to rename a table in Transaction, SQL Server automatically puts schema locks so that INSERT statement is blocked until the locks on tblName1 are released. Also the problem with the above code is that you can't name the table to temp_tblName1 the second time.

Comment: @Afr: I was looking for a lock in SQL Server but it seems like I'll end up using `ReaderWriterLock` in C# because SQL locks are too confusing for me and I can't find a good explanation on how they work. The `temp_tblName1` table is deleted after it is processed. The second SQL chunk is not called before that. As to what you said about automatic locks, as we found out from an answer here (that was later deleted) that if two of those SQL code chunks are run concurrently from 2 or more threads they need synchronization to work correctly.

Comment: @afr is correct. The code you have above is correct from a locking perspective.  However, I'd question if the approach you are taking is correct.  Why is it necessary to rename the table to process it? Why do still want to go with a lock when you admit they are too confusing and you don't know how they work?  The reason you are getting multiple comments suggesting you take different approach is because the approach you are using is very rarely the best one.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments have suggested, consider doing this differently.  You may benefit from using the [snapshot isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).  Using snapshot isolation requires `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` to be set to `ON` on the database.  This setting is off by default, so you'll want to check whether you can turn it on.

Once you are able to use snapshot isolation, you would not need to change your `INSERT` statement, but your other process could change to something like:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- Do whatever this process does, but don't rename the table.

-- If you want to get rid of the old records:
DELETE [tblName1] WHERE 1 = 1
-- Then
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

In case you really do need to create a new non-temporary table for some reason, you may need to do so before entering the transaction, as there are some limits on what you are allowed to do during snapshot isolation.